# how to change all visible:hidden into display:none by jquery?

Tags: jquery, css

```
<div style="visibility:hidden;">a</div>
<div style="visibility:visible;">b</div>
<div style="visibility:hidden;">c</div>
<div style="visibility:visible;">d</div>

if($('*').css( "visibility", "hidden" )
{
    $(This).css("display", "none");
}
```

How to search through entire page to find all elements that visibility :hidden and then add display:none on it? Something like the code above :

Comment: That is selection all the elements and setting it to hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select it by the style if there is no other elements and the style attribute is exact. In real world scenario, it is not reliable.

```js
$('div[style="visibility:hidden;"]').css('display', 'none')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="visibility:hidden;">a</div>
<div style="visibility:visible;">b</div>
<div style="visibility:hidden;">c</div>
<div style="visibility:visible;">d</div>
```

Instead select the elements you want and loop over them check that each one is set to visible or hidden.

```js
$('div').each(function () {
  if (this.style.visibility === 'hidden') {
    $(this).css('display', 'none')
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="visibility:hidden;">a</div>
<div style="visibility:visible;">b</div>
<div style="visibility:hidden;">c</div>
<div style="visibility:visible;">d</div>
```

Comment: perfect. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
$('*').each(function(index, el) {
  if (el.style.visibility == 'hidden')
    el.style.display = 'none';
});
```